# What happens if we use extra parenthesis() in mathematical expression?

Tags: c++, gcc

```
double res = (double)((a*b)/(a+b));
```

After trying the above code with inputs 80,70 I am getting the output 37 not 37.333 but after removing one parenthesis i got the right answer.

The right code is:

```
double res = (double)(a*b)/(a+b);
```

I am using:
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)

Comment: 1. First Case
 
       double res = (double)((a*b)/(a+b));

   In this case, for the input 80 and 70, the evaluation goes as ->

       res = (double)((70*80)/(70+80)) = (double)((5600)/(150)) = (double)(37) = 37

2. Second Case

       double res = (double)(a*b)/(a+b);

   In this case, for the input 80 and 70, the evaluation goes as ->

       res = (double)(70*80)/(70+80) = (double)(5600)/(150) = 5600.0/150 = 37.33

Comment: Worked for me.  I even simplified with less parens and no unnecessary cast.  `double a = 80; double b = 70; double res = (a*b)/(a+b);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double res = (double)((a*b)/(a+b));
```

Casting to double after integer math is applied, where values might have been truncated. Resort to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

```
double res = (double)(a*b)/(a+b);
```

Here the cast is performed before the divison.

Comment: "rounded down' - they are truncated. I know, distinction without a difference :)

Comment: @VladFeinstein agreed.

Comment: @VladFeinstein — they’re not the same. Truncating `-1.5` gives `-1`. Rounding it down gives `-2`.

Comment: @PeteBecker it depends on your definition of "down" :) I think of it is "towards 0"